# High latency - dense-sparse mode PIM

Tags: cisco-catalyst, multicast

Colleagues, good day!

In my prod, I notice large delays to some switches behind which there are hosts with multicast reception

I wanted to know if my multicast is set up correctly, is it normal that there is no RP in the output, and as I understand it correctly, the multicast is now working in the Dense Mod mode? What do I need in order to set up the RP, will there be less traffic from this?

Current settings:

```
interface Vlan61
 ip address 10.1.61.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
interface Vlan73
 ip address 10.1.73.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
interface Vlan1101
 ip address 10.1.255.244 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode

 SW1#show ip pim neig
Address                                                            Prio/Mode
10.1.255.242      Vlan1101                 20w5d/00:01:22    v2    1 / S P G
10.1.255.241      Vlan1101                 20w5d/00:01:20    v2    1 / S P G
10.1.255.245      Vlan1101                 20w5d/00:01:31    v2    1 / DR S P G
10.1.255.243      Vlan1101                 20w5d/00:01:37    v2    1 / S P G
10.1.255.1        Vlan1101                 20w5d/00:01:42    v2    1 / S P G

SW1#show ip pim autorp
  AutoRP is enabled.
  RP Discovery packet MTU is 0.
  224.0.1.40 is joined on Vlan61.

PIM AutoRP Statistics: Sent/Received
  RP Announce: 0/0, RP Discovery: 0/0



 SW1##show ip pim rp
  SW1##
```

Traffic sources can be from different networks, both from vlan 1101 to the client, for example, in vlan 61 and 73, and vice versa.

```
(10.1.73.2, 239.255.255.253), 00:00:47/00:02:12, flags: T
   Incoming interface: Vlan73, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
   Outgoing interface list:
     Vlan61, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:00:47/stopped
     Vlan1101, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:00:47/stopped


(10.1.1.6, 239.255.255.253), 00:00:28/00:02:31, flags: T
   Incoming interface: Vlan1101, RPF nbr 10.1.255.241
   Outgoing interface list:
     Vlan61, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:00:28/stopped
     Vlan73, Forward/Sparse-Dense, 00:00:28/stopped
```

All 5 neighbors shown above are distribution level switches connected to the higher core, in turn, about 20 access level switches are connected to each switch, where the recipients are located (vlan 71 and 63)

show ip mroute:
The output of the command is too large, so I will not post it

show ip igmp-snooping commands:
there are all vlans enabled, but except for those where there are clients, it seems to me that it is now necessary to enable it there as well.

Comment: Please add more information to your question, such as:  From SW1's perspective, where are the mcast sources (all incoming through VLAN 1101)? Where are the mcast receivers (VLAN 71, VLAN 63), and are the receivers attached to SW1 or downstream L2 Switches?  On the L2 infra downstream from SW1, do the switches support IGMP Snooping?  Please also include `show ip mroute` and `show ip igmp snooping groups` from SW1.  - - - oh and yes, you will need a Rendez-Vous point with PIM Sparse-Dense mode.

Comment: (I'll get back with more info or an answer later)  `but except for those where there are clients, it seems to me that it is now necessary to enable it there as well`
Yes, absolutely.  While multicast routers use PIM to talk to each other, IGMP is spoken between mcast receviers ("clients") and their "first" mcast router.  Therefore, more than anywhere else, *IGMP snooping* is needed on the L2 switches (respectivley on the VLANs) between that first mcast router and the receivers. With IGMP snooping, the switches can "spy" on the IGMP exchanges between receiver and their router(s).

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need in order to set up the RP,

(Paraphrasing from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/solutions_docs/ip_multicast/White_papers/rps.html#wp1029526)

Designate the router to be the Rendez-Vous Point. Where you will put your RP mostly depends on the (multicast) routing topology of your network.

Commonly, RPs are implemented on a central routing hop between sources and receivers. Mostly, that will be the core routers, sometimes the L3 switches at the distribution layer.

Be sure to understand your network topology, how it's IGP is set up, how it makes use of redundant paths, and based on that, you can determine where to place the RP, while makiung sure the network can also provide redundant RPs (the *Anycast with MSDP* scenario well suited to provide RP redundancy).

To configure the RP: Add an additional Loopback IP address, enable it for PIM sparse-mode and make sure its /32 address is distributed within the given IGP (OSPF, EIGRP,...).

```
interface Loopback1
 description **** Anycast RP Looback ****
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.255
 ip pim sparse-mode
 ip ospf 100 interface area a.a.a.a

router ospf 100 
 ...
```

Then select one way of how other PIM routers learn about that IP address (Auto-RP, BSR, static mapping , static mapping with anycast & MSDP) - see the cisco document linked above.

All non-RP mcast routers then must be configured to know what IP address the RP has, like this:

```
ip pim rp-address 10.0.13.1
```

The IGP (OSPF, EIGRP) will let them know through wich (upstream) interface they can reach the RP.

> will there be less traffic from this?

Yes, for multicast traffic being forwarded from router to router, PIM sparse-dense-mode with its RP certainly helps to conserve resources on the routers.

Remember the first rule of forwarding multicast for a *router*: Replicate or "multify" received mcast traffic through all (mcast enabled) interfaces, *except* the ingress interface. Back in the day of software-based forwarding and general-purpose CPUs in routers, this could quickly become a burden for an underpowered CPU in a router.

PIM and sparse/dense mode certainly help here: A router will only need to replicate traffic towards the RP (if upstream towards RP) or (if downstream from RP) towards PIM neighbors which have interested receivers, either  connected directly or further downstream.

So having a properly configured RP will help in the Layer3/Routing enabled parts of your network, which will probably be core and distribution layer.

In the **Access Layer** though, L2 switches will treat multicast as broadcast. A 25Mbit/s mcast stream will have to be replicated to all active ports of the given VLAN.

Think of the simple access switch with all its 48ports in the same VLAN.
Its switching ASIC will have to "multify" those 25Mbit/s of incoming traffic from the uplink to a sum of 1.2Gbit/sec and replicate it through all interfaces. That very old 10Mbit/s printer on port 47 of the access switch will have a very bad networking day.

Here's where **IGMP snooping** helps. The L2 switch can observe how clients/receivers send IGMP messages to let their "first hop" multicast router know they want to receive a given group/stream.

From snooping on the client's IGMP messages, and from the IGMP query messages from the first hop router, the L2 switch can build its own (local) L2 multicast forwarding table, and it will not have to replicate mcast traffic onto switchports where no system requested them. And the legacy printer's 10Mbit/s switchport won't be bothered.

TL;DR

From the few symptoms you described, I suggest to

- set up an RP in a suitable manner that fits your network
  topology and the population of mcast enabled end systems (sources,
  receivers)
- implement IGMP snooping at the access layer
- be sure to remove any L2 switches without IGMP snooping support from your switching tree.

Please consider adding a network topology diagram to your question, so we might better understand the situation.

Comment: Thanks!All fine!